# Automated Padding for Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, text, responsive-design, responsive

On the home page of a website I created, I made the text element "News and Announcements" appear under "Upcoming Events" on mobile devices. However, these texts are always changing, and therefore the padding I established to put space between the elements can never be a set number. For example, currently the "News and Announcements" text is very long, so it does not have enough padding and overlaps with "Upcoming Events". Currently, I have it set with media queries at breakpoints every time it needs more padding. However, this would have to be changed every time the website is updated, which would be very tedious. Is there any way to automate this padding so it sets differently every time more or less text is added?

http://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/ALPojE

(note: my website has a flexslider, but it doesn't appear in codepen)

HTML

```
<div id="contentTwo">

<div id="insert1">

<div id="insert1_title">
News and Announcements 
</div><!-- end title -->

<div id="insert1_textblock">

<div id="insert1_text">
<div id="link"><a>eChoices Application period opens October 4th!!</a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">The eChoices application period opens on October 4th and ends on November 10th at 5:00pm. Please visit: <a href="http://echoices.lausd.net" target="new">echoices.lausd.net</a> to apply.</div>
<!-- end description -->  
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="insert1_text">
<div id="link"><a>October is the College &amp; Career Month</a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">Bancroft will be highlighting this month with activities, trivia,  and information. All 7th and 8th grade students will be taking the PSAT on 10/19/2016.</div>
<!-- end description -->  
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="insert1_text">
<div id="link"><a>PHBAO Conferences scheduled for Thursday October 20th 5-7 pm</a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">We are half-way through the Fall semester! Parent-Teacher conference night is coming. Report cards will be handed out from 4-6 pm. Teachers are available to meet with parents from 5-7 pm. Please focus on meeting with teachers if your child is struggling (C-D-Fail-U) in a class</div>
<!-- end description -->  
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="insert1_text">
<div id="link"><a>Annual Title I Meeting scheduled for Thursday October 20th 7 pm</a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">The Every Child Succeeds Act  requires that  parents be informed about their rights under the Title I Program and how to become involved in improving the school's Title I program, including development and evaluation of the school's parent involvement policy.</div>
<!-- end description -->  
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="insert1_text">
<div id="link"><a>There is still space in our STE[+a]M and Performing Arts Magnets for Spring Semester!</a><a href="magnet_tour_2016.html" target="new"></a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">Are you looking for a school that will challenge your child while engaging them in the arts (art, dance, music, theatre) or engineering (Project Lead the Way Gateway curriculum)? All students participate in our International Baccalaureate Programme which includes a world language (Mandarin or Spanish) every year. Come visit us!</div>
<!-- end description --> 
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="insert1_text">
<div id="link"><a href="magnet_tour_2016.html" target="new">Magnet Tour Dates Announced!</a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">Come visit us and see our STE[+a]M and Performing Arts Magnets! Click the title above for a link to dates and more information on our Magnet Tours.</div>
<!-- end description --> 
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="insert1_text">
<div id="link"><a href="magnet_tour_2016.html" target="new">Bancroft's Title IX Complaint Managers</a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">
  <p style="margin: 0;">Counselor Aldana: 1-323-933-3407 <a href="mailto:ealdan1@lausd.net" target="new"> Send Email</a> </p>
  <p style="margin: 0;">Counselor Llamas: 1-323-993-3407 <a href="mailto:mxl5422@lausd.net"> Send Email</a></p>
  <p style="margin: 0;">For the District's Title IX Sex Based Nondiscrimination Statute <a href="" target="new">Click here. </a></p>
<!-- that link was a bit.ly shortened link, but stackoverflow didn't want those types of links -->
</div>
<!-- end description --> 
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->



</div><!-- end insert1 text block --> 
</div><!-- end insert 1 -->

<div id="insert2">

<div id="insert2_title">
Upcoming Events
</div><!-- end title -->

<div id="insert2_textblock">

<div id="insert2_text">
<div id="link">
  <div id="insert2_text2">
    <div id="link2"><a>School Site Council Meeting</a></div>
    <!-- end link -->
    <div id="description2">
      <p style="margin: 0;">Date: 10/18/2016, 3:30 pm </p>
      <p style="margin: 0;">Location: School Library </p>
    </div>
    <!-- end description -->
    <hr noshade="noshade" />
  </div>
  <a>PSAT Test Day </a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">
  <p style="margin: 0;">Date: 10/19/2016, 8 am - 12 noon</p>
</div>
<!-- end description -->  
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="insert2_text">
<div id="link"><a>PHBAO Parent-Teacher Conferences</a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">
  <p style="margin: 0;">Date: 10/20/2016, 5-7 p.m </p>
</div>
<!-- end description -->  
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="insert2_text">
<div id="link"><a>Minimum Day - school ends at 12:45 pm</a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">
  <p style="margin: 0;">Date: 10/21/2016 - school buses leave at 3:00 pm</p>
</div>
<!-- end description -->  
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="insert2_text">
<div id="link"><a>Magnet Tour</a></div>
<!-- end link -->
<div id="description">
  <p style="margin: 0;">Date: 10/26/2016, 10:30 a.m</p>
</div>
<!-- end description -->  
<hr noshade="noshade" />
</div><!-- end text -->

<div id="feature">
<a href="http://bancroftmiddleschool.org/BancroftTours.html"target="new">Virtual Tour</a>

<div id="feature-content" style="text-decoration:none"> Never seen the Bancroft Campus? Click the title above for a virtual tour!</div><!-- end feature content--->

</div><!-- end feature -->

<!-- video html & css should be in index copies---> 

</div><!-- end text block --> 

</div><!-- end insert2 -->

</div><!-- content 2 -->
```

CSS

```
#contentTwo   {
    height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#insert2 {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 28%;
    padding-right: 70px;
}

#contentTwo #insert1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 53%; 
    padding-left: 122px;
    float: left;
}

#contentTwo #insert1 #insert1_textblock {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 500px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#container #main #contentTwo #insert2 #insert2_textblock {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 510px;
}
#container #main #contentTwo #insert1 p {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#contentTwo #insert1 #insert1_title {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentTwo #insert2 #insert2_title {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#container #main #contentTwo #insert1 #insert1_text {
    margin: 5px;
    color: #465C8B;
}
#contentTwo #insert1 #insert1_textblock #insert1_text #link a {
    color: #465C8B;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#insert2 #insert2_textblock #insert2_text {
    margin: 10px;
    color: #465C8B;
}
#contentTwo #insert2 #insert2_textblock #insert2_text #link a {
    color: #465C8B;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#contentTwo #insert1 #insert1_text #description {
    color: #465C8B;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1010px){

#contentTwo   {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    clear: both;
}

#insert2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    clear: both;
}

#contentTwo #insert1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px;
    clear: both;
}

#contentTwo #insert1 #insert1_text #description {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 800px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 50px;  
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 735px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 100px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 560px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 150px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 510px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 200px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 460px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 250px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 422px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 350px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 360px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 450px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 338px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 550px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 280px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 650px; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 250px){
    #insert2{
        padding-top: 750px; 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I just spent A LOT of time fixing the padding to new breakpoints, which is what I want to avoid. here is the product http://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/bwxAwJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pixel-based heights on divs aren't necessary; once you get rid of those, the vertical padding won't be necessary either. CSS will just stack your stuff on its own.

Edit: So: remove your height declarations from #contentTwo, #contentTwo #insert1 #insert1_textblock, #container #main #contentTwo #insert2 #insert2_textblock. That way your divs will stack with automatic heights and not with pixel-based declarations, which means they won't overlap each other.

Then you'll be able to float #insert-1 left and float #insert-2 right. After that, you'll want to clear your floats for the two columns. (For more information on floats and clearing them, see https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ ). In this instance, the easiest way to do it is to add overflow:hidden to the parent container, which in this case is #content-2.

Comment: Do you mean the height for content 2 div, the 550 px?

Comment: *and inserts*, I can just delete them and nothing bad will happen?

Comment: I deleted the height properties from content 2 and the textboxes, and it really messed things up, what should I do? Set them to 100%?

Comment: that also messed things up. Can you please clarify?

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained what code should be removed; the OP has provided their code; you can modify it.

Comment: Do I delete the property itself? Do I change it? Can you please clarify?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes, thank you. Do you have nay ideas?

Comment: *any (woops, typo)

Comment: No, this answer showed up in a review queue, and I wanted to prompt  @TheGreatHambino to update his answer with more specificity before it got deleted.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ok, thank you for helping. If you can, can you send this to anyone you think has an answer, or spread the word? This website updates daily, and changing that padding daily would be such a hassle.

Comment: Alright, so I pulled out that middle section (no header, no footer) and put it into a CodePen here for you - http://codepen.io/timhamilton/pen/mAGrrz?editors=1100#0 . There's a lot of best-practices other stuff that we could look at as well, but essentially I removed all of the pixel-based heights from items like this: `#container #main #contentTwo #insert2 #insert2_textblock {
 padding: 5px;
 height: 510px;
}`

Comment: @TheGreatHambino But I do want the two texts to be side by side before the 1010px break point I had it at. Would that affect anything?

Comment: Yeah, just keep your floats wherever you want them. I added them in at the very bottom of the CSS; you can modify the placement of them depending on your breakpoints.

Comment: @TheGreatHambino I'm pretty sure that's why I set the height to insert2 originally, for the two texts to be side by side. Any way that they can be?

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: When I added your changes (which worked so well, thank you) it affected other elements such as the navigation bar and footer. It is hard to explain what's happening, so here is a link http://bancroftmiddleschool.org/index%20copy.html

Comment: http://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/bwxAwJ the effects are also in here

Comment: Are you talking about that blue thing in the middle of the screen? That's part of your footer, and that happens because the floats you added for the two columns weren't cleared properly. One way to do this in this instance would be to add overflow:hidden to #contentTwo. (You should also delete #space from your markup.) For more info, take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: @TheGreatHambino yes, there is that, and did you notice how the nav bar follows your scroll? Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @TheGreatHambino nevermind, the clearing the float fixed that. Thank you so much for everything!

Comment: Yeah, your nav is set to position: absolute. Remove that. Then set #nav > ul to margin: 0, which will put it back to the way it was looking before (with no grey spacing above and below).

Comment: @TheGreatHambino As I said before, it would be great if you could update the answer with more information. CodePen's great and all, but if it goes down, or these comments are deleted (they often are), this answer won't help anyone. See, for example, [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260411/215552).

Comment: Done - one reason I hesitated to do that was that OP's question seemed so specific to his/her code. So I'm wondering if even the question will be useful to anyone else besides OP...